# HTML table creation with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, html-table

Can anyone show me how to create this table with DOM html javascript. I've tried to make a function that finds an element by ID and adds to the existing `<table class="overflow-y"></table>` tags. However I can't find a way of viewing the html code I generating and don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
<table id="mytable" class="overflow-y">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>corner</th><th>header1</th><th>header2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><td>1-1</td><td>1-2</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>row2</th><td>2-1</td><td>2-2</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>row3</th><td>3-1</td><td>3-2</td><
    </tr><tr>
      <th>row4</th><td>4-1</td><td>4-2</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <th>row25</th><td>5-1</td><td>5-2</td
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [dinamyc rows](https://jsfiddle.net/eldien/v2t3g1r2/)

Comment: The dynamic rows is nearly what I'm looking for @OmarYafer but I have a dynamic number of columns as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the example I made in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eldien/ygjpwnhb/).

Consider this HTML structure

```
<table id="myTable" class="table">
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<button class="button" id="addRow">Row +</button>
<button class="button" id="addColumn">Column + </button>
```

In the html you have buttons to add columns and rows.

And with the following jquery functions you control the way you generate the the rows and columns.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var myTable = $('#myTable');
    addRows(myTable);
    addColumns(myTable);

  });

  function addRows(table){
    $('#addRow').click(function(){
        var lastRow = $('#myTable > tbody > tr:last-child'); //fetch last row so you can copy it. You will need to find a way to copy only the structure.


      if(lastRow.length > 0){
        table.append(lastRow.clone()); //Append a copy of the last row to the table
      }
      else{
        table.append($('<tr></tr>')); //create an empty row
      }
    });
  }

  function addColumns(table){
    $('#addColumn').click(function(){
            var rows = $('#myTable > tbody > tr'); //Get all rows
        rows.append($('<td>Column</td>')); //Append a td to all rows in the body
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

In your final code you will need to:

- Control the number of columns so that you don´t get a weird table.
- Add an input so that you can add th to a

Hope it helps you getting started.

Comment: This looks very nice, I've never used JQuery but I shall get going with a few tutorials then edit your code. I think I shall add arguments for the number of rows/ colums to the functions so the table can be built when the html page loads up. Many thanks.